# Language Support on Linux Mint Debian Edition

Tags: linux-mint, locale, settings

After a new install of Linux Mint Debian Edition I have some words unlocalized to my native language:

[image: language missing]

most in Czech, some words in English.

Whenever I've installed Ubuntu/Linux Mint this always happened, but then I just clicked on "language center" and it automaticilly asked me if I want to install the remaining language packages.

[image: language support]
(this is a an ubuntu screen, but it was almost the same thing on Linux Mint)

However, on the new Linux Mint Debian Edition (with MATE) I cannot find that language support window. It's not in the Control Panel. How can I install the remaining packages?

Comment: btw I am not afraid of any console solution - I just dont know which packages to download...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to open `Synaptic`, the package manager (`sudo synaptic`) and search for "Czech". You can do the same thing from the command line (which is easier to post here) as follows:

```
sudo apt-cache search czech
```

The last command returns a list of 59 packages on my system, the ones you need are:

```
task-czech - Czech environment
task-czech-desktop - Czech desktop
```

Thise should fix your desktop. Depending on the software you have installed, you may also want to install one of these for spelling

```
aspell-cs - Czech dictionary for GNU Aspell
iczech - The Czech dictionary for ispell
myspell-cs - Czech dictionary for myspell
```

Also the localization files for whichever office suite you have installed (libreoffice is the default):

```
libreoffice-help-cs - office productivity suite -- Czech help
libreoffice-l10n-cs - office productivity suite -- Czech language package

openoffice.org-help-cs - office productivity suite -- Czech help
openoffice.org-l10n-cs - office productivity suite -- Czech language package
```

Once you choose the files you want, you can install them with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install task-czech task-czech-desktop myspell-cs libreoffice-help-cs libreoffice-l10n-cs
```

Comment: thx i was able to put thunderbird and others to czech now. however the right click on Desktop still produces the same menu as on the picture in my original post. it's a detail I wonder how to solve it though..

Comment: @aGr I'm not sure they work with MATE, but did you install `task-czech` and `task-czech-desktop`? I also found [this site](http://www.linux-mint-czech.cz/) which may be helpful to you (don't speak Czech so I don't know).

Comment: yeah i did. thx i'll look into it